# to_s && include? questions involving inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, output

I am coming from Java and some C++ and am learning (some of) ruby through creating a blackjack game. I am meticulously going through this program to understand how ruby really works.

The code at hand is:

```
class Card
  include Comparable
  include Enumerable
  attr_accessor :value
  def initialize(v)
    @value = v
  end
  def <=>(other)
    if other.is_a?(Card)
      @value <=> other.value
    else
      @value <=> other
    end
  end
  def each
    yield @value
  end
  def to_s
    "#{@value}"
  end
end

class Hand <  Card
  include Enumerable
  attr_accessor :hand
  def initialize
    @hand = Array.new()
  end
  def clear_hand
    @hand.clear
  end
  def add_to_hand(c)
    if c.is_a?(Card)
      @hand << c
    else
      raise "We have a problem - we received a non card object into our hand"
    end
  end
  def each
    @hand.each do |card|
      yield card
    end
  end
  def to_s
    @hand.each do |c|
      puts c
    end
  end
end

c1 = Card.new(3)
c2 = Card.new(0)
p = Hand.new()
p.add_to_hand(c1)
puts c1 # => 3
puts p  # => 3 \n(new line) #<Hand:0x00000002b01ba0>
puts [1,2,3,4,5].include?(c1)  # => true
puts [1,2,3,4,5].include?(p)   # => false
```

My questions:

Why, when I use 'puts p' do I get an ObjectID along with the expected value '3'.It only does this with arrays (or that is all I have noticed so far, but i'm sure there are other cases where it returns the ObjectID also). Could someone please explain why.

And the final line (when we get the false output) I would like it to return true - this is because I have a Hand, which is full of cards (only one at this point), and it does contain the card with the value 3. So, I do not know what is wrong with my code that causes this to return false - I yield each card of the "hand", which I believe should then yield that value by using the each statement of card?

If this is unclear please let me know!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prints out your object because the [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) method returns with the object itself. If you want to return only the cards in the `Hand` simply return the array instead, or the joined version:

```
def to_s
  @hand.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: did you say earlier that I forgot to do the <==> in my hand class also? or was that somewhere else or did i make that up? and thanks!

Comment: @user2243357 No, you did not make it up, I deleted that part because it was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-to_s) says:
Returns a string representing obj. The default `to_s` prints the object’s class and an encoding of the object id.

Now if you do below :

```
p Hand.ancestors 
#=> [Hand, Card, Enumerable, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As you don't define `to_s` any of your class `Hand` and `Card`, thus `Object#to_s` is called by the `puts`. Just to prove it place the code below in you `Hand` class:

```
  def to_s
   "I am Hand class Object"
  end
```

Now call `puts p`, you would see the output : `I am Hand class Object`.

But [`Array#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-inspect) overloads the `Object#to_s`. Thus prints different output.

*Now coming to your second confusion:*

[`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) says -

> Returns true if the given object is present in self (that is, if any object == object), otherwise returns false.

Which means in your case the array `[1,2,3,4,5]` contains `Fixnum` objects. Thus [`Fixnum#==`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3D-3D) will be called. `Fixnum#==` says ***Return true if fix equals other numerically.***. But `p` your `Hand` class object doesn't meet that said condition, for each call like `1==p`,`2==p`,so on,thus `false` value has been returned.

Hope it helps you to understand the concept.